# Help understanding the word 'topographical'

Tags: meaning

My girlfriend keeps seeing the word topographical appear in her social work coursework, and asked me what it meant in this context.

I'm struggling to help explain clearly, can you help break it down?

Comment: Of or relating to [topography](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/topography) -- I guess there's a particular specialised nuance for social workers. The question arises, why doesn't your girlfriend simply ask her tutors?

Comment: She's on her Christmas holiday and tutors are unavailable.

Comment: I never understood why [Tales from Topographic Oceans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_Topographic_Oceans) was called that, and I'm still none the wiser after reading in that Wikipedia link about how Wakeman originally wanted to use his made-up word *Tobographic* (don't ask me - something to do with Fred Hoyle, apparently!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Crankshaft](http://what-when-how.com/social-sciences/topography-social-science/) explains how *topography* is used in social science to discuss societal relationship with place.

> Translated literally from its Greek roots of *topos* (place) and *graphein* (to write), *topography* means "the writing of place." In modern usage, however, the term has taken on more complex significance. ... In social science, topographies (both representational and actual) are of interest to researchers investigating relationships between societies and local environments.
>
> ... In different ways, authors and others have moved understandings of topographies beyond concern for merely the material configuration of places and instead highlighted the multiplicity of ways in which humans become attached to and interact with places.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the section 'relationships between societies and local environments' was a lightbulb moment for her!

Comment: Perhaps a rider is advisable, to the effect that this is a subject-specific usage, not found amongst the several definitions at the AHDEL, for instance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Feel free to add one, if the introductory sentence is not enough.

Comment: It's certainly the correct answer to Felix's girlfriend's problem, but I think that there's enough valuable discussion posted on the website to warrant researcher-friendly asides (which is probably why I seemingly get regular downvotes). (Or it could be the puns.)